# Navbar disappears after one second on smaller screens in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using bootstrap to implement a toggling navbar. On smaller screens, it toggles, but when I click the icon the navbar appears and disappears after one second. Can anyone help?
I will share the nav bar code below. As you can see I have added the necessary classes but still, the navbar disappears after one second on a smaller screen. I am new to bootstrap. Please help me

```
<nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-sm  fixed-top navbar-default">  
                <div class="navbar-header ">
                    <span  class="navbar-brand"> <img class="rounded d-inline-block align-top  "src="./mr.jpg" height="30px" width="30px" >HARISH</a></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                <button class="navbar-toggler  collapsed navbar-light " type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target = "#navbar" aria-controls = "navbarNav" aria-expanded = "false" aria-label = "Toggle navigation "> 
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggleable" id="navbar">
                    <ul class=" nav navbar-nav ">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link a-style" href="#">Reviews</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link a-style" href="#">About us</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link a-style" href="#">FAQ</a>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </div> 
            </nav>
```

Comment: Have you added the bootstrap css and javascript links?

Comment: Yes ,I have added the links. @godfather

Answer (score 0):

Try This...

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
          
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Dropdown
                  </a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it didn't work.